# Restriction caused by substitution

Tags: integration

We often come across integrals where we use various substitutions to reduce our problem. A common one is the trigonometric substitution.

When we substitute $x=\sin \theta$,  aren't we restricting $x$'s values to $[-1,1]$?

Here's a quick example:

$$\int_2^3 xdx$$

In this case, $x$ is always in $[2,3]$. So is $x=\sin \theta$ a valid substitution here?

In general, I would like to say that a substitution in an indefinite integration is valid, if and only if the variable substituted has the same range as the new variable.

Comment: You're right that that substitution isn't valid. You'd confirm that when you tried to change the limits of integration $2$ and $3$—there are no counterparts in the $\theta$ variable, as you've noted.

Comment: So substitution heavily relies on the bounds. Doesn't that shake the whole world of indefinite integration?

Comment: I wouldn't say so (although I like the instinct to push math to see if it breaks!). Indefinite integrals are usually done without reference to a specific domain, so a method that gives a correct answer on a convenient domain will also give that answer elsewhere. If you try the indefinite integral $\int x\,dx$ using this substitution, you will indeed find your way back to $\frac12x^2+C$. Finally, really we can use any method of finding antiderivatives we feel like (including monkeys typing or sceances)—because at the end of the day we can always check our answer for accuracy!

Comment: I understand, but I would argue that you cannot use $x=\sin \theta $ while finding the indefinite integration of $x$, since its not true everywhere!

Comment: That argument would be stronger if you could find a situation where using a substitution like that actually gave a wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

You 'run' a definite integral over a set. In a way you can think of a ' definite integral' as a procedure which takes in a subset(S) of $\mathrm{R}$ and tells the area of a function underneath the curve and x-axis in that interval.

[image]

When you do a change of variables, since you are changing the function you are integrating, you must also change the set you are integrating over. If you have are integrating over a set $[a,b]$ and you do a substitution of the form below:

$$ x= g(t)$$

Then, in the new domain of $t$, your domain is transformed like so:

$$ [a,b] \to [ g^{-1} (a) , g^{-1} (b) ] $$

[image: ![enter image description here]

You can think that as we vary 't', we vary $g(t)$ and this, in turn, varies the output. And, so, **yes we can only do a substitution if the $g(t)$ can span the original domain which we were integrating over.**

Given the above, if you are doing a change of variables, first of all, you need to make sure there is a well-defined inverse function of the new function you are integrating such that you can change your bounds properly.

In the particular case, it seems we can't find $ \sin^{-1} (2)$ or $ \sin^{-1} (3)$ whilst constrained to the set of reals. And hence, that substitution is not feasible in this case.